# Zero Free Region of $\zeta(s)$

Tags: analytic-number-theory

There exists a positive numerical constant $c$ such that $\zeta(s)$ has no
zero in the region $\sigma \geq 1-\frac{c}{\log(|t|+2)}$

Davenport's Multiplicative Number Theory writes this on page $86$, and I am unsure what it says. I am assuming that $\zeta(s) \neq 0$ whenever $s$ satisfies $Re(s) \geq 1-\frac{c}{\log(|Im(s)|+2)}$ where $s$ is a complex number. Is this interpretation correct?

Also I searched MSE but other questions has simmilar statement but not this one.

Comment: Your interpretation seems correct to me :)

Comment: Almost every book I read on $\zeta(s)$ uses the convention $s=\sigma+it$ for $\sigma,t\in\mathbb R$.